# Java webstart heap dump

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have been trying to get webstart to dump to a heap dump when it runs out of memory.

I know the jmap/jconsole way of doing it, but what I really want to do is add the option to jnlp file and have tried the following options.

1. j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-server +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" max-heap-size="768M"
2. j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" max-heap-size="768M"

Comment: What results go you get when you run the program with those options?

Comment: since that involves manipulating the client's computer (dumping a file to the local computer).  i wouldn't be surprised if there are security controls around this option.  it may be completely denied, or may require extra permissions.

Comment: Have you tried also specifying the path by adding for example `-XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will definetly not work when you place this option to the jnlp file. There is a list of allowed options and the others will be ignored. You can check the list of available JVM options in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).

Note that the idea is that end-user will run you application on his computer. What would you do with the heap dump on his comp? It might be anyone in the world running your app. It won't make much sense if you were allowed to do this with end users JVM through your JNLP file.

The only situation I can think about would be you have access to that computer and you can check the dump later. In that case (you as a end user request the dump) it is actually possible if you bypass the autorun of the jnlp file from the browser and run it yourself via the `javaws` command. The steps I have taken and which lead to success were as follows (assume the jnlp file was `testOOM.jnlp` and you are on windows):

1. Download the JNLP file
2. from the command line navigate to the directory with the JNLP file
3. execute `javaws -verbose -J-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError testOOM.jnlp`

Using this the app will be launched in the very same way as from the browser. But notice the `-J` option which allows you to supply JVM options to the JVM. This is ok because it is the ebd user client who requested the dump.

On `OutOfMemoryError` the heap dump will be stored in the same directory where you run your `javaws` command from.

Comment: Thanks very much, we are distributing internally so we can actually get the dumps, will see if we can get a script to execute it

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me that a developer may want a webstart application to generate a heap dump. You're right that in a production app with lots of users that the developer doesn't have direct contact with, this would be unuseful. However, during development there are beta users, test users, and users that are also on the development team. This is my case... and they are savvy enough to get the heap dump file to me if it is generated. Having this option would be exceptionally useful and makes a whole lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Java 7 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html), the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option is now supported for a webstart application ([RFE: 6664424](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6664424)).

Comment: Anyone knows were the heap file is created?