# " -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory" option still does not work in Java webstart using JDK 7

Tags: java, java-web-start

I came to know some other post that JNLP now supports XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory from Java 7:
[Java webstart heap dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663736/java-webstart-heap-dump)
I am trying to set the same in java-vm-args but it is not being displayed in the system deployment properties (by clicking s in Java console) and also if my application goes out of memory (OOM) I am not getting any heap dump generated at Java's working directory.
Any help in this regard is appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that **`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory` VM argument is not supported in JNLP** on Java 6, 7 and 8.

See [JNLP File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html), section *The following java-vm-args are supported by this version*